# How to get error name in batch when I use OSQL command?

Tags: sql-server-2005, batch-file, osql

I created a batch file which execute a sql command.

Let's see the piece of code

```
SET OSQL="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\osql.exe"
IF NOT EXIST %OSQL% ECHO OSQL.EXE not found, please check the OSQL variable!
IF NOT EXIST %OSQL% GOTO :ERROR

SET SQLQUERY_UPDATEDB = "SELECT * FROM %DB%";

%OSQL% -S %SQLSERVERNAME% -d %DBNAME% -U %DBACCOUNT% -P %DBPASSWORD% -Q %SQLQUERY_UPDATEDB% -n -b -m-1 > D:\sqloutput.txt

:ERROR
ECHO Sorry, could not complete your request!
ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%
GOTO :END

:END
ECHO Finish batch
```

The above part of code returns always 0 and `Sorry, could not complete your request!` . What does mean ?

How to set up to display error in console to see exactly what does wrong ?

I put `-m-1` and I removed `-h-1` accordingly with [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162806.aspx) but doesn't show up in my console.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um. Because even if it runs the SQL Command successfully, it then drops into the error handler?

Try adding a `GOTO :END` after you run the command:

```
SET SQLQUERY_UPDATEDB = "SELECT * FROM %DB%";

%OSQL% -S %SQLSERVERNAME% -d %DBNAME% -U %DBACCOUNT% -P %DBPASSWORD% -Q %SQLQUERY_UPDATEDB% -n -b -m-1 > D:\sqloutput.txt
GOTO :END

:ERROR
```

Comment: And how can I see if error occured in console ? It is a possibility to do that ? or is a dream ?

Comment: Yeah, I cannot see because I set up `@ECHO OFF` at begin of file :)